# Prestashop product edit page new tab module

Tags: tabs, product, prestashop

I'm creating module to add additional tab into edit product page called "Instructiuons". I have overrided AdminProductsController, but i have problems with tab tpl file, i dont know how to install it by module. It must be like "SEO" tab and ect. Can you help? Im working with 1.5

Comment: it is more easy as i think, just need to add hook "displayAdminProductsExtra" into module

Answer (score 0):

i think there is a hook called "displayAdminProductsExtra" you can display any fields while adding/editing a product and after save the product you can call this hook "actionProductAdd"